# Int size overflow when executing this part of the program

Tags: c, debugging, scanf, overflow

when I am running this program I am getting an overflow and I do not know how to fix it. The program is a square matrix power calculator, and it obtains input from a text file. It reads from a file that is formatted as such:

```
3 // size of a square matrix so in this case a 3X3 matrix
1 2 3 // all these numbers are inputs for each [i][j] entry
4 5 6
7 8 9
2// exponent to perform multiplication
```

The code has an edge case where if you enter matrix size 1, then you just need to perform a power operation on the next int give by the exponent given on the line following. This is where I am running into overflow. Any advice?

```
int size;

    fscanf(file, "%d", &size);
    
    if(size==1){
        int n;
        int exp;
        int res = pow(n,exp);
        fscanf(file, "%d", &n);
        fscanf(file, "%d", &exp);
        
        printf("%d",res);   
    }
```

Edit: Assume all inputs are in the correct format.

Comment: `pow()` is being called with unitialized values. Maybe you mean to call `pow()` after `fscanf()` ?

Comment: @sj95126 let me see if that fixes it

Comment: @sj95126 unfortunately not, I was getting even more issues so I decided to use a for loop to do the power, yet I keep getting an Int Overflow stating: `-1094795586 * -1094795586 cannot be represented in type 'int'`

Comment: @sj95126 btw, I am not inputting those numbers my test case is size =1 entry = 12 exponent = 2, so the expected result is 144

Comment: I tried by moving the `int res = pow(n, exp);` line to the empty line before `printf`, and `file` to `stdin`, input: `1 12 2`, prints `144`. Try with these changes (including the `file` to `stdin` and manually entering that exact input), and _remove all other code_ apart from the necessary `int main() { … return 0; }` wrapper. If that makes the problem go away (it should), put your changes back one at a time and see which breaks it.

Comment: BTW, random thought: `exp` is also a function. Could you be accidentally using it somewhere where your `int exp` is not in scope, and using the address of the function as a value? Turn on all compiler warnings (and fix any that you get).

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you debug your program by replacing all fscanf() with simple assignments like this:

```c
size = 3; // fscanf(file, "%d", &size);
```

Then run your code again. If you get the overflow then it has nothing to do with reading the file. If this does fix the problem, then try adding printf() after each fscanf() to inspect what the value is, like this:

```c
fscanf(file, "%d", &size);
printf("size = %d \n\r", size);
```